# OS X's "free" or "/proc/meminfo" equivalent

Tags: memory, kernel

OS X lacks the "Linux-friendly" `free` or `/proc/meminfo`.

What would be the most reliable and backwards-compatible way of extracting this info:

- Current free memory, in bytes

Going back as far as possible in terms of OS versions, without requiring extensions like `ports`, `brew`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

The closest analogs to `free` and `cat /proc/meminfo` might be:

- `vm_stat` and
- `ls -l /var/vm`

but you also have the BSD tools like `heap` and Darwin tool `allmemory` to dig deeper into processes and libraries to determine how the overall virtual memory load is allocated to specific processes.